# using variables versus hardcoding in a where clause with mysql for nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the npm mysql driver for nodejs.
How can I use a variable in the where clause of a query?

//------This does not work.Here I am using the variable in the where clause.------

```
app.get('/query1', function (req, res) {    
  var seat_id = req.query.seat_id

connection.query('SELECT * FROM seatpic where seatsid = "seat_id" ',function(err,rows,fields){
  if(err){
    console.log('There is an error in the query!');
  }else {
    console.log("value of var seat_id is:" ,seat_id);
        console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
        console.log(rows);
}

        res.json (rows)

});

});


//-----This works. Hardcoding the where clause with a number.---------


app.get('/query1', function (req, res) {    
  var seat_id = req.query.seat_id

connection.query('SELECT * FROM seatpic where seatsid = 6 ',function(err,rows,fields){
  if(err){
    console.log('There is an error in the query!');
  }else {
    console.log("value of var seat_id is:" ,seat_id);
        console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
        console.log(rows);
}

        res.json (rows)

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?` in your query and provide values as an array as follows

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM seatpic where seatsid = ?", [seatid], function(err,rows,fields){...
```

where `[seatid]` is an array with your dynamic value.

See the following for more - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved and thanks for the link for explanation.